# Safari interpreting datetime string differently than chrome

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi

Please see the attached screenshots. Why is this happening and what is the best solution?

The code for both is:

```
var d = new Date("2018-03-30T00:00:00");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
```

[Chrome behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDqeU.png)

> Fri Mar 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

[Safari behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV6ou.png)

> Thu Mar 29 2018 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

Comment: Please put your code and the results as text directly into the question

Comment: This doesn't appear to be happening in Safari 15. Does anyone know what version of Safari fixed this?

Answer (score 1):

One of your browsers is assuming the input is in a different timezone to the other.

Try creating the date with timezone information:

```
var d = new Date("2018-03-30T00:00:00.000Z");
```

or,

```
var d = new Date("Fri, 30 Mar 2018 00:00:00 GMT");
```

Comment: I don't want this conversion. This is actually date of birth and I have stored no timezone information in database. I just want safari to interpret the date as it is.

Comment: @nabeelriaz that's not really how dates work. You could write your app to assume everything is UTC, but there will trouble ahead. The first example treats the date as UTC, so you could just add the `Z` to everything.

Comment: Right now, What I have done is 
user.dob = new Date(user.dob.toString() + "Z");
            user.dob = new Date(user.dob.getUTCFullYear(), user.dob.getUTCMonth(), user.dob.getUTCDate());
            
It is behaving as expected. Is it an OK approach?